# MongoDB connected but data not fetched from mongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am facing a serious issue in MongoDB. I am using expressjs and mongoose with DataBase MongoDB. The issue is when I configure the database it consoles successfully connected but when I run the endpoint for fetching data, It always returns an empty array all the time. the same database is connected with robo3t and it works fine. please help me.
Note: Database have a bulk of data.

Comment: Hello, Better to post your code!

Comment: Post your code please, but before that set mongoose event listeners and check if mongodb connected successfully.
For example use `const db = mongoose.connect(...)`
And then use  `db.on('error', callback)` or `db.on('connect', callback)`